# How to log in as a user in p4

Tags: version-control, perforce

I have an issue where users are trying to log in to their perforce account using p4 (not p4v), but it seems to start at a default account without permissions.  When they try to logout with `p4 logout`, they get "Access for user "foo" has not been enabled by 'p4 protect'".

What is the standard way of logging out and logging in via p4?

Comment: What security level is your server running (I'm assuming level 3) and are your clients Windows or Linux (or other)?

Comment: Security level I'm not sure of... I was not the one to set up the server.  The clients are Linux

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Perforce uses two environment variables, `P4PORT` and `P4USER` (there are others, but these are the two you need). If `P4PORT` is undefined, it'll default to `perforce:1666` and if `P4USER` is undefined, it'll default to the currently logged in username (on Linux it gets this form the `USER` variable). If that user doesn't exist in perforce, you'll see the message you described.

If you need clients to log in as a different username from their Linux one, they need to run:

```
export P4PORT=<server:port>
export P4USER=<perforce username>
p4 login
```

The error occurs if the server hasn't been set up to automatically create a user account on first access; and the username defned in `P4USER` (or the inferred one from `USER`) doesn't exist in the database.

Comment: You'll get that error at any security level unless the server has been set up to automatically create a user account when a user accesses the server for the first time.

Comment: Checkout the user guide especially on the use of P4CONFIG: http://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/manuals/p4guide/chapter.configuration.html#DB5-24024